# Could an interrupt be serviced while the scheduler is changing the current task to another(i mean the scheduler is doing thread context switching)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, scheduling

Interruptions could be handled while process is runing at the time of interruption occurs. Could an interrupt be serviced while the scheduler is changing the current task to another(i mean the scheduler is doing thread context switching)?

I would be grateful for any hint on this question.

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "while process context is switching". Do you mean for example while the process is in the middle of a syscall (which requires a context switch)?

Comment: The process context forementioned is which could switch from the current thread to another thread.I have followed your advice and have revised it.

Comment: That is not context switching, that's preemption and it's a completely different thing. Do you want to know whether an interrupt can be serviced while the scheduler is changing the current task after preempting it? Please, update your question and clarify with enough detail what you are asking for, otherwise it's impossible to answer.

Comment: I see.Sorry for disturbing you.I would go out of my way to make my question easy to understand, though i am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible, the schedule() function will disable interrupt before doing the context switch.

```
static void __sched notrace __schedule(bool preempt)
{
    struct task_struct *prev, *next;
    unsigned long *switch_count;
    struct rq_flags rf;
    struct rq *rq;
    int cpu;

    cpu = smp_processor_id();
    rq = cpu_rq(cpu);
    prev = rq->curr;

    schedule_debug(prev);
    if (sched_feat(HRTICK))
        hrtick_clear(rq);

    //look at here
    local_irq_disable();
......
};
```

Here is the [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7-rc1/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L4006), and I write [a blog about that](https://ty-chen.github.io/linux-kernel-schedule/), maybe helpful for you.

Comment: As you say, `schedule` will disable interrupt before doing the context switch.So the conclusion should be that no interrupt could be serviced while the scheduler is changing the current task.Do you intend to say "impossible", not "possible"?

Comment: It may interrupt in some specific time such as before `disable` or after `enable`, but when doing the thing between `disable` and `enable`, interrupt can not be executed.

Comment: Could you post the url related  to the code in your answer?

Comment: Chen, thank you very much.I woud read the document carefully.Do you have some ideas about how to measure the duation to switch threads?On most platform, how long does it take?